# Get focused window name on haskell (Windows)

Tags: windows, haskell

I want to write timetracker. There is exist any way to know focused window name on Haskell?

Comment: It would probably be through the win32api if anything. I would look up how to do it there then figure out how to talk to that library with haskell. There are win32 libraries already written, but I don't personally know how complete they are.

Comment: Thank you! As I understand there are no documentation on win32 package (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32). Seems like thats libraries are very "rough" now.

Comment: The latest version that has working Haddock links on Hackage is [2.2.2.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.2.2.0) (I assume the documentation buildbots don't use Windows). It's still in that lovely "automatic list of functions and their types with no comments" style we're all so fond of. Although that may be because it's a heap of bindings to standard Windows API that's documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `Win32` package or call the Windows API directly.

You can use `getForegroundWindow` to get the handle to the the focused window and then use `GetWindowText` or `GetWindowInfo` depending on what you want.

The `Win32` is unlikely to get any documentation as you can enter the exact same functions on MSDN and get documentation. Only extra functionality written by us will be documented. The reason is that we'd have to keep up with the documentation on MSDN and there just isn't the man power.

I have been looking into automation, so if that succeeds then maybe :)